# vagrant: Share ssh folder between host and guest

Tags: ssh, vagrant

In order to `bundle` and connect to Github as my normal self within my VM, I'd like to `config.vm.share_folder "ssh", "/home/vagrant/.ssh", "~/.ssh"`.

Except this breaks vagrant's public/private key authentication.

#### Attempted Solution #1

I tried to copy my public key to also be `authorized_keys`. Same behavior; I need to enter a password to `vagrant ssh`.

#### Attempted Solution #2

Copy the public key to `authorized_keys`, but also set `config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_dsa"`. This just screwed everything up, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want to look into is SSH agent forwarding. [Vagrant has a configuration option to enable this](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/ssh/forward_agent.html). If you are already running an SSH agent locally this is definitely the way to go.

In fact, even if you aren't running an SSH agent, I would still suggest looking into it.

An alternate, but horribly dirty, solution might be to use a [vagrant shell provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/shell.html) to place your private key in ~/.ssh/ and set the relevant entries in ~/.ssh/config. Something like:

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_non_vagrant_key
```